# UML Component symbol: Do the two blocks on the left represent something specific?

Tags: uml, components, component-diagram

I have just received a diagram from a colleague, which I must now extend. It has numerous components, all of which are drawn using the following symbol.

[image]

I understand this is a "component" in UML component diagrams.

The diagram I've received has lines going out of the two blocks on the left to various other components, presumably to indicate a relationship with those other components.

Do the two blocks on the left have specific meanings? Is (for example) the top one input and the bottom one output? Or do they not have any specific meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1)** According to Kirill Fakhroutdinov's explanation of the term  `Component` in [uml-diagrams.org: UML Component Diagrams](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams.html#component) this is an UML 1.4 notation which still can be used for backward compatibility reasons.

Looking into the documents associated with UML Version 1.4 published by OMG back in 2001 you can find an example which clearly shows

> Source: http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/1.4/PDF/index.htm
>
> [image]
>
> Figure 3-94 Component Diagram

that the two blocks originally **did not have any specific meaning**.

**(2)** Similar notation with the meaning of input and output [pin](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-objects.html#pin) is used in UML activity diagrams, as shown in the picture below

> Source: [Conrad Bock, UML 2 Activity and Action Models, Part 4: Object Nodes](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2004_01/column3/)
>
> [image]
>
> Figure 14: Avoiding Deadlock

**(3)** For your work of extending the legacy diagram you may find useful an [uml-diagrams.org: UML component diagram example for online shopping](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/examples/online-shopping-uml-component-diagram-example.html?context=cmp-examples)